# Kubernetes: customizing Pod scheduling and Volume scheduling

Tags: kubernetes, scheduling, volume, persistent

I'm trying to use Kubernetes to manage a scenario where I need to run several instances of an application (that is, several Pods). These are my requirements:

1. When I need to scale up my application, I want to deploy one single Pod on a specific Node (not a random one).
2. When I need to scale down my application, I want to remove a specific Pod from a specific Node (not a random one).
3. When a new Pod is deployed, I want it to mount a specific PersistentVolume (not a random one) that I have manually provisioned.
4. After a Pod has been deleted, I want its PersistentVolume to be re-usable by a different Pod.

So far, I used this naive solution to do all of the above: every time I needed to create a new instance of my application, I created one new Deployment (with exactly one replica) and one PersistentVolumeClaim. So for example, if I need five instances of my application, then I need five Deployments. Though, this solution is not very scalable and it doesn't exploit the full potential of Kubernetes.

I think it would be a lot smarter to use one single template for all the Pods, but I'm not sure whether I should use a Deployment or a Statefulset.

I've been experimenting with Labels and Node Affinity, and I found out that I can satisfy requirement 1, but I cannot satisfy requirement 2 this way. In order to satisfy requirement 2, **would it be possible to delete a specific Pod by writing my own custom scheduler?**

I don't understand how Kubernetes decides to tie a specific PersistentVolume to a specific PersistentVolumeClaim. **Is there a sort of volume scheduler? Can I customize it somehow?** This way, every time a new Pod is created, I'd be able to tie it to a specific volume.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a good reason for these requirements so I'm not going to try to convince you that it may not be a good idea to use Kubernetes for this...

Yes - with nodeSelector using labels, [node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity-beta-feature), and [anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) rules, pods can be scheduled on "appropriate" nodes.

[Static Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/static-pod/) may be something close to what you are looking for. I've never used static pods/bare pods on Kubernetes...they kind of don't (to quote something from the question) "...exploit the full potential of Kubernetes" ;-)

Otherwise, here is what I think will work with out-of-the-box constructs for the four requirements:

Use Deployment like you have - this will give you requirements #1 and #2. I don't believe requirement #2 (nor #1, actually) can be satisfied with StatefulSet. Neither with a [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/).

Use statically provisioned PVs and [selector(s)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#selector) to (quote) "...tie a specific PersistentVolume to a specific PersistentVolumeClaim" for requirement #3.

Then requirement #4 will be possible - just make sure the PVs use the proper [reclaim policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaim-policy).

Comment: By using a Deployment (like I'm trying to do now), I can satisfy #1 by using Labels and Node Affinity, but these are only considered at schedule-time, not at execution-time. This means that if I delete a label from a specific Node, the Pod running on that Node will not be deleted (failing to satisfy #2). Or am I missing something here? I have already tried deleting a Label and reducing the replicas number by one, but it didn't work as intended.

Moreover, a Deployment constitutes a single "template" for all of the Pods. Can I specify a single PVC for each Pod of a Deployment? If so, how?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. By saying "...Use Deployment like you have [been]" I meant what you were describing as "...one new Deployment (with exactly one replica) and one PersistentVolumeClaim" for every new instance of the application.

Comment: Oh ok. Yes, I've managed to make it work that way, but I would still like to improve my solution now :)